# Find the closest point on a ray from another point

Tags: c++, math, graphics

I'm currently in the process of making a 3D engine and for lighting one of the things I have to do is cast a 3d ray and the find the point on that ray that is closest to another given point. My question is does anyone know of an efficient way of doing that within code?

To be more specific I am casting a ray with a specific origin p and a direction d in a 3D world and given another 3d point c I would like to find the point on that ray that is closest to c.

Comment: This seems to be college-level calculus. Compute the formula for the distance between the "3d point c" and any point on "a ray with a specific origin p and a direction d". This should be a simple formula. Then calculate its derivative. Solve for the derivative equal to 0. Mission accomplished? When dealing with highly specialized, math-heavy situations like that, basic programming skills are not enough; one needs to be skilled in calculus.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are familiar with vectors (as in Linear Algebra)

```
// Here, Vector is a vector in Rn, not a dynamic array.
Vector v = c - p;
float dotProd = dot(v, d);
dotProd = max(dotProd, 0.0f); // if dotProd is negative, the closest point is in the opposite direction to d.
Vector e = p + d * dotProd;
```

Now, e is the closest point to c on the ray

Answer (score 2):

an image is worth thousand words, so an image + a few words with maths formulas is worth thousand + few words.

[image]